# Trying to add an image to subfolder in 'Albums' of iPhone Photos app 'Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died'

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I was trying to create a folder 'temp folder' under 'Albums' in Photos iPhone app and then add an image/images into the 'temp folder'. When the image added successfully I saw no warning in my debug pane, but once in a while I saw this on the the debug pane 'Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died' and image did not save. 
I am using PHPhotoLibrary to do this. If anyone has the same problems please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough memory free/open; delete (all?) many background tasks and try again. If the error doesn't show up, you're good to go.

Comment: I removed many of the open app from Multi-Task and it seems to help a lot. Thanks.